# A map for fuzzy logics.

Tags: logic, reference-request, fuzzy-logic

I'm studying metatheorems of fuzzy logics and I found this  [map of fuzzy logics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx9Ve.png) that relates multiple fuzzy logics and I was wondering two things:

First I would like to know if anyone knows where this map is extracted from, I got the images some time ago and don't remember where I downloaded from.

Second I would like to know if someone know any maps that relate different fuzzy logics in a similar fashion as in the map I found.

Comment: For the first point: try googling for the first few words of the caption of the figure. Your second point is too vague (although you'll find some more interesting figures when you do the google search).